# Gpm_Open() connects, but prints to the console on mouse click

Tags: terminal, console, mouse, xterm

I am trying to use libgpm, looks like the program detects mouse clicks,
but as a side effect it prints something like this to the terminal:

```
^[[M <7^[[M#<7^[[M <7^[[M#<7^[[M <7^[[M#<7^[[M <7^[[M#<7^[[M Y=^[[M#M<^[[M !=^[[M#)=
```

Even if I remove any calls to `Gpm_Getc()`, leaving the code as simple as this:

```
#include <gpm.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Gpm_Connect conn;
    int c;

    conn.eventMask = 0;
    conn.defaultMask = ~0;
    conn.minMod = 0;
    conn.maxMod = ~0;

    if (Gpm_Open(&conn, 0) == -1)
        printf("Cannot connect to mouse server\n");

    while (1);

    Gpm_Close();
    return 0;
}
```

I still see those gibberish codes. I reckon, they represent the mouse events. But in my code there is no direct instruction to print them. Why are  they printed to my terminal? How can this be avoided?

I use gnome-terminal on linux, not a real console, if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `TERM` environment variable is `xterm`, GPM won't try to open the Linux console.

Instead, it simply turns on **xterm** mouse-mode (which makes the terminal send escape sequences), and it turns out, expects the ***application*** to handle that rather than transforming the escape sequences into its protocol.

From ncurses' viewpoint, for instance, that makes its behavior in a terminal emulator less than useful, and the library checks for this case and ignores GPM (since [2010](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/NEWS.html#t20100327)).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now I realize that interacting with mouse could fully be fully solved with ncurses. In fact I cannot even use ncurses with libgpm together.

Comment: That depends - if ncurses is configured with gpm, it uses that in Linux console, but xterm protocol otherwise.  Some packagers may not have configured it with gpm...